# String.Format changes to EU format when deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2019

So I have a solution that I'm about to deploy to IIS. Currently, everything works fine in my debug environment, and my `String.Format()` for dollars is correct i.e.:

```
string.Format("{0:#,0.00}", myMoney)
//Outputs 100,00.00
```

However, when deployed to IIS things change slightly, here my strings with currency shows in an european format, i.e. 100.00,00...

I have tried a bunch of things thus far, without any luck, let me recap here:

- Changed globalization in IIS from invariant to en_US in both Culture and UICulture
- Changed region of the server to be US
- Changed region of the client to be US

I'm running windows server 2019 with IIS 10.0.017763.1

Still, I'm stuck with the same problem. What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will other overloading method string.Format(cultureInfo,format,args) an option? In this case you can specify your desired culture.

Comment: That worked. But why is this necessary? Can't I just tell IIS to treat it like dollars, like it does in my debug?

Comment: maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/980215/asp-net-core-site-has-the-wrong-default-culture-when-run-with-iis) can help.

Comment: Did not help me - I will keep this up for a few more hours to get more responses, otherwise i will approve your answer.. Would prefer not to set the cultureinfo in every string.format though

Comment: IIS sometime is weird. If you don't want to set cultureInfo in every string.Format. You can set the default one for your application like [this](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/06/22/request-culture-asp-net-core/)